# Sencha Touch Use Icon With Selectlist In Toolbar

Tags: sencha-touch, selectlist

I would like to use a selectlist in a toolbar but have a icon. For example someone wishes to select there radius for a places search around them I want to show an icon then when clicked allow the user to select different options ie (50meters, 1Kilometer, 10Kilometers).

Is there a better way to do this than a selectlist? Is this possioble with a select list in a tool bar? When I try to do it the selectlist shows the first value.

I trying to accomplish this with sencha touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create two buttons over there : one with the label and another with the value. Then on both the buttons add one handler to open a floating panel showed by the second button.

Something like this:

```
{
    xtype : 'toolbar',
    defaults : {
        scope ; this,
        handler : showDistanceList,
        ui :'plain'
    },
    items : [{
       text : 'Some label',
       id : 'label_btn'
    }, {
       text : '5 km',           //default 5 km
       id : 'value_btn'
    }]
}


function showDistanceList(btn){
    var distanceListPanel = new Ext.Panel({
         floating : true,
         width : 200,
         height : 300,
         //items : someListComponent
    });

    distanceListPanel.showBy(btn);   

    // Set value button value here with the selected list value 
    // Ext.getCmp('value_btn').setValue('value of item selected from list');        
}
```

For the buttons, you can use any icons or html elements.

Comment: Wow thank you that makes so many more possibilities by creating floating panels and your explanation was very clear. Just started using sencha last week and I love it so far! Again great answer.